# JSONAPIAdapter - Use camel case instead of dasherized case

Tags: ember-data

Is there a quick and easy way to use `camel case` when serializing a JsonApi model?  By default is is using `dasherized case` for both url and field names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [EmberJS guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_path-customization) for an example how to make `user-profile`-related adapter hit `user_profile` instead:

```
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(type) {
      return Ember.String.underscore(type);
  }
});
```

> Requests for `person` would now target `/person/1`. Requests for `user-profile` would now target `/user_profile/1`

If you need to serialize attributes, not just the model names, you can find related section to the topic at the very same place, direct link [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_customizing-serializers).

Since the example above uses `Ember.String.underscore()`, I am attaching a link to very useful String helpers Ember provides by default, [Ember.String API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html):

- [camelize](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/String/methods/camelize?anchor=camelize)
- [capitalize](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_capitalize)
- [classify](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_classify)
- [dasherize](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_dasherize)
- [decamelize](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_decamelize)
- [htmlSafe](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_htmlSafe)
- [loc](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_loc)
- [underscore](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_underscore)
- [w](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_w)